# angular 4 ngFor doesn't update list when add

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an object called "objective" that have a list of objects "keyresults" inside. Every objective has a list of keyresults. When I select an objective, I have access to the list of keyresults of this objective through a modal. So, in this modal, I have a field that I can add a new key result, I just put the name and click Add. But, when I add a new keyresult, the list doesn't update, I need to refresh the page and select the objective again to see the new key result.
I want that the list update and show the new key result just after I add a new. How can I do this?

My html modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-md-9" style="float:left; border-right:solid">
        <b>{{itemSelected.title}}</b>
        <select [(ngModel)]="itemSelected.state" (change)="updateState(itemSelected.state)">
            >
            <option *ngFor="let item of states" [value]="item.Id">{{item.Name}}</option>
        </select>
        <p>{{itemSelected.description}}</p>
        <div>
            <b>{{itemSelected.dueDate}}</b>
            <b>{{itemSelected.ownerPersonName}}</b>
        </div>
        <br />

        <b>Key Results</b>
        <hr />
        <div *ngFor="let keyResult of itemSelected.keyResults">
            {{keyResult.description}}
        </div>

        <input [(ngModel)]="newKeyResult.description" type="text">

        <select [(ngModel)]="newKeyResult.metricType">
            <option *ngFor="let item of keyResultTypes" [value]="item.Id">{{item.Name}}</option>
        </select>

        <button type="button" (click)="addKeyResult(itemSelected.id)">Adicionar</button>
        <br />
        <div *ngIf="successKeyResult" class="alert alert-success">{{successKeyResult}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="errorKeyResult" class="alert alert-danger">{{errorKeyResult}}</div>
    </div>
```

My TS method:

```
private addKeyResult(objectiveId: any) {
    this.objectiveService.addKeyResult(objectiveId, this.newKeyResult).subscribe((ok) => {
        console.log(ok);
        this.successKeyResult = "KeyResult adicionado com sucesso";
    }, (error) => {
        this.errorKeyResult = this.objectiveService.getError(error.status);
    });
}
```

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

Hugo Noro helped me with the solution. I just need to add two lines in my method "addKeyResult" to update the client side list after saving it:

```
this.itemSelected.keyResults = [...this.itemSelected.keyResults, this.newKeyResult];
this.newKeyResult = {};
```

Like this:

```
private addKeyResult(objectiveId: any) {
    this.newKeyResult.metricValueFrom = 0;
    this.newKeyResult.metricValueTo = 0;
    this.newKeyResult.actualValue = 0;
    this.newKeyResult.state = 0;

    this.objectiveService.addKeyResult(objectiveId, this.newKeyResult).subscribe((ok) => {
        console.log(ok);
        this.itemSelected.keyResults = [...this.itemSelected.keyResults, this.newKeyResult];
        this.successKeyResult = "KeyResult adicionado com sucesso";
        this.newKeyResult = {};
    }, (error) => {
        this.errorKeyResult = this.objectiveService.getError(error.status);
    });
}
```

Comment: When your `addResult` call returns what are you receiving from your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so my understanding here is that you are effectively persisting the addition of the new key on the server by calling the service but you are not updating the client side list after saving it.

Try something like this

```
private addKeyResult(objectiveId: any) {
this.objectiveService.addKeyResult(objectiveId, this.newKeyResult).subscribe((ok) => {
    this.itemSelected.keyResults = [...this.itemSelected.keyResults, this.newKeyResult];
console.log(ok);
    this.successKeyResult = "KeyResult adicionado com sucesso";
}, (error) => {
    this.errorKeyResult = this.objectiveService.getError(error.status);
});
}
```

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you so much!!!! I just added a "this.newKeyResult = {}" after your line code to unlink the entry from the new key result.

Thank you so much!!! You helped me a lot!

Comment: No worries. Always glad to help :)

Comment: It’s also a good SO practice to share your working solution. If you please edit your answer to include it, it would be helpful for others.